# Time of detecting ibeacon: background and foreground time

Tags: ibeacon-android

In detect ibeacon, why we should detect them in background and foreground. what should we do in background and foreground. and time to do them.

Answer (score 1):

The question was tagged with ibeacon-android, so here is information about background and foreground iBeacon detection times using the Android [iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/).

When an Android app is in the foreground, the library will generally detect an iBeacon within 1100 ms (about 1 second) provided that the iBeacon is transmitting at least that quickly.  This is true for both the monitoring and ranging APIs.  There are some cases where radio noise can cause individual advertisements to be missed, delaying the detection by a second or so, but it is still very, very fast.

The open source Android iBeacon Library allows you to indicate when your app is in the background, and if you do so, it will by default slow down checks for iBeacons to once every 10 minutes to save battery.  This background scan interval is fully customizable.  If you have the Pro version of the library, the background/foreground determination is automatic.  Full details on how this works can be found [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/pro/battery_manager.html).